# Spyder vs jupyter notebook - printing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spyder

Hello guys [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNHBU.png)

absolute Python newbie here, i´m kinda self learning following an online course. my final objective is to use python for scientific purposes (data analysis, writing down functions to calculate stuff, acquiring data and signals from a device, control such a device etc.). i´m using Spyder IDE to write code and exercise, while the guy in the online course videos uses Jupyter notebook. my problem is really not a problem, but i noticed that sometimes i have to use a different code on Spyder to get the same results he does with the notebook. i´ll give you guys an example:

Online Training code (Jupyter)

```
def add_five(input_list)
    output_list = []
    for element in input_list
        element = element + 5
        output_list.append(element)
    return output_list
input_list = [5,1 20]
add_five(input_list)
```

now, with this code, he gets the print of the output list without adding anything (see the screenshot), which kinda baffles me since he doesn´t call a print anywhere.

when i try to recreate the code on my pc with Spyder, in order to get the same result, i have to implement a print within the function. without the print, the program runs but i don´t get any output.
also, i declared the global variable right away, just for my own peace of mind.

```
input_list = [5,34,56,78,98,78]
def add_five(input_list):
    output_list = []
    for element in input_list:
        element = element + 5
        output_list.append(element)
    print(output_list)
    return output_list
add_five(input_list)
```

any idea why the difference? do i have some settings in Spyder wrong?
Thank you all and sorry for the noobness of the question, i hope i´ll come up with more juicy stuff in the future.
Take care
Francesco

Comment: Really it's just a feature of Jupyter that the last line's return is printed. It would be more similar in Spyder if you remove the `print` from the function and instead did `print(add_five(input_list))`

Comment: @JNevill
yeah i´m getting around how it works, for example later on he uses the map function to do the same, and to get the output he simply calls the `list(output_list)` whereas for me it would be `print(list(output_list))`

thank you